# iOS UI Test Datepicker

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uitest

I'm making a UI Test for an iOS app. I'm having trouble finding out how to use automated testing for a date picker. Right now I'm stuck trying to find the date picker itself so I can change the values.

I've searched many threads regarding this issue but have found nothing.

If anyone has any insight to this it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried accessibility identifiers?

Comment: Yes. I figured it would be as easy as setting an accessibilitylabel and using that like datePickers["myLabel"] .

However, it still has trouble finding it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get started, I'd advise you to use the "Record UI Test" button in Xcode to easily find out how to access the `UIDatePicker` in the UI Test.

For a simple `UIDatePicker` in `date` mode, changing the date is as simple as:

```
let datePickers = XCUIApplication().datePickers
datePickers.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "June")
datePickers.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 1).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "1")
datePickers.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 2).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "2015")
```

If the datePicker is connected to a `UILabel`, you could then check if the text in the label has been updated correctly.

Comment: Huh... It really was that easy. Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone, supporting multiple localizations, an easier way would be

```
 let dateComponent = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
 let monthText = formatter.string(from: Date())

 datePicker.pickerWheels[String(dateComponent.year!)].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "2017")
 datePicker.pickerWheels[monthText].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "December")
 datePicker.pickerWheels[String(dateComponent.day!)].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "21")
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped a lot!

Comment: that's a good idea, but I guess it will only work if you haven't programmatically set a different date to your date picker (`Date()` is the default)

Answer (score 0):

In the very end, I gave up, since all solutions are flaky, depending on the device's locale and date. Then I thought by myself: why should I even test this whole UI element? If you need to change date somewhere in your flow, you are better off doing something like this:

1. Add 2 `Button`s, one with a `goForward` SFSymbol and one with `goBackwards`.
2. Add them in your view with the DatePickers, surrounded by `#if DEBUG` statements
3. When the user presses one of the buttons, increase/decrease your `DatePicker` by a predefined static value. That way, you can still test different dates, but no more flaky tests.